# Is the continuous extension theorem true when the range space of $f$ is not complete?

Tags: analysis, continuity, uniform-continuity

So the problem is Exercise $13$, Chap. $4$ of *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Rudin:

***Problem***

Let $E$ be a dense subset of metric space $X$, and let $f$ be a uniformly continuous ***real*** function defined on $E$. Prove that $f$ has a continuous extension from $E$ to $X$.

Following the hint given by the author, I am able to prove this result and understand that the result still holds when the range space of $f$ is replaced by any ***complete*** metric space. My question is, does the result also hold when the range space is ***any*** metric space? If yes, how to prove, if no, are there any illuminating counterexamples?

Comment: There's a very simple example of a continuous $f:\mathbb Q\to\mathbb Q$ that cannot be extended to a continuous map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich What is it? I tried $f(x) = x$, but it looks OK to me.

Comment: ?????????????????

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I am asking for your "very simple example", thank you. I tried to use $f(x) = x, x \in \mathbb{Q}$ with the range $\mathbb{Q}$ as a counterexample, but I think $g(x) = x, x \in \mathbb{R}$ is its valid continuous extension.

Comment: @Zhanxiong: So you claim that $x \in \Bbb{Q}$ for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$? Note that we require the extension to still have range in $\Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong If we say $g(x)=x$ then $g$ maps $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb Q$???

Comment: @PhoemueX I think although the range of $f$ should be restricted to $\mathbb{Q}$, $g$ doesn't need to be.

Comment: @PhoemueX Oh, really?

Comment: @Zhanxiong: If you do not require that, it is trivially true. Let $f : E \to Y$ (with $Y$ possibly incomplete) be uniformly continuous. Let $\overline{Y} \supset Y$ be the completion of $Y$. Interpret $f$ as a map $f : E \to \overline{Y}$. By what you have shown, there is a continuous extension $g : X \to \overline{Y}$. But if you require the extension to still have rang in $Y$ (and not in some potentially bigger space), then in general the extension is not possible.

Comment: @PhoemueX OK, thank you, I understand. I should have argued like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f:\Bbb Q\to \Bbb Q,\, f(x)=x$. Were there some continuous extension $g:\Bbb R\to \Bbb Q$, would it be possible to define $g(\sqrt 2)$?

PS: I just did exactly this same problem in Baby Rudin yesterday :)

Answer (score 0):

The uniformity is necessary. If a sequence in E satisfies the Cauchy criterion,with respect to the metric on X, the uniform continuity of f implies that the image of this sequence also satisfies the Cauchy condition so the image sequence converges to a limit point y.Now if the sequence in E as no limit point inX,there is nothing to do,but if it has a limit point p in X\E, we define f(p)=y.This value is independent of which which sequence in E,converging to p,was chosen.To show that f is continuous on all of X, consider that if a sequence in X converges to a point q, then each term in the sequence is arbitrarily close to a member of E, and use the uniformity of f on E to show that the image sequence converges to f(p) whether p is in E or in X/E.(I think you can finish this). The completeness (or not) of X is irrelevant..... On the other hand,if you have already proved the theorem for complete metric spaces, and X is not complete, then let cX be the metric completion of X. Now E is dense in X and X is dense in cX so E is dense in cX. So extend f from E to cX and then restrict it to X..... The theorem is not true when the range is not a complete metric space,because a sequence in E may converge to a point in X/E when the image of the sequence may be a Cauchy sequence with no point to converge to.For example, if X =R (the reals, with the usual metric)),E=R/{0} and E is also the range of f,with f(x)=x for x in E.